# Autoblog - WPMU DEV unable to edit post Permalink

Tags: wordpress, wpmu, autoblogged

I have installed Autoblog - WPMU DEV  plugin in my site and i have imported some blogs using feed .

But when i published the blog post only some content and image is appearing in home page ,and once we click that its taking me to original site blog post .

And also i am unable to edit the post Permalink . The blog Permalink is linking to original blog post

[image]

can any one tell where i am wrong . or auto blog will work in this way only ? (i have assumed that we copy all the content and images to my site using this plugin )